# MySQL : Calculate business day difference between two dates column

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query returns back two columns, first column is "date created" and second column is "date updated", first column has a prior timestamp with respect to second column.

I need to add a third column which can display business day hrs (9:00am to 5:00pm) response i.e. if date created is 2012-01-04 09:00:20  and "dated updated" is 4:00pm same day then third column should display 7 hrs

If date created is 2012-01-04 16:00:20  (4:00pm) and "date updated" is 10:00m on 2012:01:05 (2nd Jan) then third column should display 2 hrs.

It should exclude Saturday and Sunday.

Can you please suggest appropriate SQL query for this.

Comment: Database platforms differ in the temporal functions they provide. Can you say which platform you're using?

Comment: Can't say I've seen dates expressed as "2012:01:01"... Besides, in many countries around the world, 4pm Jan 1 to 10am Jan 2 constitutes 0 work hours, being public holidays. Do you handle non-working days besides Sat and Sun?

Comment: Hi Richard, I would like to neglect Sat and Sun and timezone doesn't matter, my server is in specific timezone and writing query for user who is in same timezone.

Comment: Hi Jeremy--- I am running queries on mysql.

Comment: You need a calendar table to specify which dates are business days and which are not.

Comment: Hi Gordon, How do I get a calendar table?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Gordon Linoff commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352254/mysql-calculate-business-day-difference-between-two-dates-column#comment18224999_13352254), you need to create a table containing your business hours:

```
CREATE TABLE business_days (
  start DATETIME NOT NULL,
  end   DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `business_days`
  (start, end)
VALUES
  ('2011-12-30 09:00', '2011-12-30 15:00'),  -- short day
  ('2012-01-03 09:00', '2012-01-03 17:00'),  -- 31st, 1st were Sat/Sun
  ('2012-01-04 09:00', '2012-01-04 17:00'),  -- 2nd was a public holiday
  ('2012-01-05 09:00', '2012-01-05 17:00'),
  -- etc.
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT   m.*,
         SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(
           LEAST(m.updated, b.end),
           GREATEST(m.created, b.start)
         ))))
FROM     my_table m JOIN business_days b
           ON b.start < m.updated AND m.created < b.end
GROUP BY m.created, m.updated  -- or some other key into my_table
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5d59/1/0).

Comment: Gordon--- Thank you for comment, I should have been careful while posting query, I am neglecting holidays I just need to consider weekdays and business hrs, I have edited initial posting to 4th Jan 2012 which is a weekday.

Comment: hi eggyal, solution seems not working, its not pulling appropriate values for dates, showing 1970 values, I am looking for business hrs value.